# Kendo UI based responsive web application

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, responsive-design, hybrid-mobile-app, kendo-mobile

We're working on a UI that will span from desktop to mobile. We've developed the UI with Kendo UI as a Single Page Application (SPA), laid on top of Bootstrap.

As we're working on refining the mobile UI, there are a few Kendo Mobile controls we'd like to implement. (Swipe, Switch, etc.)

But now I'm wondering which approach we should actually take:

1. Responsive site: desktop to mobile
2. Desktop site (Kendo UI) + Hybrid Mobile app (HTML + JS + CSS + Kendo on Cordova)

Has anyone had success with Option 1? It seems like a huge time saver to develop one complete system. We're not doing heavy data manipulation / editing, so we don't exactly need a distinct mobile UI. Can you point me to any blogs / articles / samples if so?

If the better solution is #2, does anyone have any suggestions for how to develop a code base with as much re-usable logic as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would depend on the app requirements.

- Network connection

Option 1 (responsive site) would require you to be online. Option 2 (mobile app) would let you be offline, but adds the complication of syncing data that is edited offline.

- App Store deployment

Hybrid app gives you the ability to deploy to app stores and have users install it.

- Hardware interaction

Does the app need to interact with any hardware? Camera, accelerometer, etc? If so then an installed hybrid app is only real choice.

---

As for code reuse, I would suggest building your JS code into "modules" using RequireJS or Browserify. Then you can reuse the modules as needed.

Comment: The "app" controls a device on the user's network through that device's API. So Network and App Store are not really issues. (The marketing benefit of an App Store deployment is minimal.)

We're also not in need of accessing device hardware.

I keep bumping into RequireJS, might be time to pick it up.

Comment: If you happen to have a Pluralsight subscription: http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/requirejs-javascript-dependency-injection and this blog post might also give you some ideas: https://codingwithspike.wordpress.com/2012/11/30/making-a-well-structured-kendo-ui-mobile-app-in-icenium-with-require-js/